# Tastypie- Append parameters to URI

Tags: django, django-urls, tastypie

How do I append parameters to a URL in Django Tastypie.

Here is url.py.

```
from modules.actions.views import InstallationResource,ApiActionsResource
from tastypie.api import Api
from modules.actions import views
v1_api = Api(api_name='v1')
v1_api.register(ApiActionsResource())

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^(?P<action_type>.+)', views.ApiActionsResource.as_view),
)
```

I need to pass `action_type=1` to the URL. How do I do it?

Answer (score 1):

You need to include your api urls like this:

```
urlpatterns = patterns(''`,
    (r'^api/', include(v1_api.urls)),
)
```

Make sure that you've set your resource name:

```
class ApiActionsResource(Resource):

    class Meta:
        resource_name = 'action_type'
```

After that, you can access any resourse in a rest way, using the resource name. 
In your case that would be: `'/api/v1/action_type/1'`

It's all explained under http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/interacting.html.