# Tastypie- 9 methods to access data

Tags: django, tastypie

I've been reading abut the tastypie Documents and I arrived on [this document](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/non_orm_data_sources.html#approach), which states 9 different method to access data. They are

detail_uri_kwargs

get_object_list

obj_get_list

obj_get

obj_create

obj_update

obj_delete_list

obj_delete

rollback

I understood few but not all. What;s the difference b/w the following 3

get_object_list

obj_get_list

obj_get

and what is `detail_uri_kwargs`?

Also, please provide your suggestions on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21531628/tastypie-append-parameters-to-uri)

Thanks in advace.

Answer (score -1):

In the documentation, I understand that:

- `get_object_list` should get all the objects.
- `obj_get_list` should get a list of filtered objects (filtered by kwargs).
- `obj_get` should get only one object, by its "pk" id.
- detail_uri_kwargs should set the "pk" of the object. You see that functions like `obj_delete` and `obj_get` assumes kwargs has the "pk" key, and they can get an unique object with that key.

Comment: How is it possible to set the pk of object?

Comment: In the ``detail_uri_kwargs`` function is up to you to code something that after receiving the object can obtain an unique pk. In the sample code the set "pk" to the uuid of ``bundle_or_obj``.

Comment: The documentation page you are referring is to set Tastypie with non-ORM data (e.g. No-SQL). Tastypie relies on Django ORM to get the ``pk`` of the objects, but if you're using other solutions, there's no *Primary key* field. That document shows you how to use uuid as the pk, i.e. some *key* that Tastypie can use to retrieve unique objects.

Comment: My situation is like this. I POST the data from my api, retrieve it at the back and then starts the celery process and without  waiting a response is sent back, ie I just dont want to POST,GET,PUT requests, instead I want other processing happening at the back, due to which I'm using the above methods. Do you have other best things in which I can do this in a more standard way? Open for suggestions/recommendations

Comment: Maybe you need this: https://github.com/celery/celery/tree/master/examples/celery_http_gateway/ or http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/remote-tasks.html, but this have little to do with the original question.

Comment: Dear negative voter: the answer is absolutely correct, as it covers all four questions asked. Would you mind to explain the negative vote so I can do something?